# tinyalsa sh: ./tinypcminfo: No such file or directory

Tags: android, tinyalsa

tinyalsa elf failed to run on android shell, anybody know what is wrong with it ?
I am new to android, :-)

here are my steps:
 1. download tinyalsa source code to a ubuntu 10 vm, compile it with arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
 2. `adb push xx\tinypcminfo /data/local/tmp`
 3. `adb shell -> cd /data/local/tmp ->chmod 777 tinypcminfo`
 4. `./tinypcminfo`
 5. error happened

Comment: It'd be useful if you will paste some information about error here: traceback, error message, whatever

Comment: Thank you andrey, I have found the reason.

Comment: so post it as answer!

Comment: ndk-build is the right way to solve this problem, because android library is different with standard c library.